# Is it ok to have multiple consumers of 1 promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Sample code:

```
const googleLoadPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    resolve(1);
  });
});

googleLoadPromise.then(function () {
 // consumer 1 - do something               
});

googleLoadPromise.then(function () {
 // comsumer 2 - do something else               
});
```

i.e. for the googleLoadPromise, there are two consumers. Is this sort of pattern ok? It seems to work ok - i.e. both consumers get called, and they don't seem to cause problems for each other.

Also, if this is ok, is the order of the running the consumers deterministic (just out of interest, more than anything)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course.
You can also just do this if you want to run both functions in sequence:

```
const googleLoadPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    resolve(1);
  });
});

googleLoadPromise
  .then(function () {
    // consumer 1 - do something
  }).then(function () {
    // comsumer 2 - do something else
});
```

Just also remember to handle rejections and `catch` your promise.

---

Promises become much easier with `async` `await` as well. The below example is more inline with what you wrote:

```
const googleLoadPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    resolve(1);
  });
});


function1 = () => {
  // consumer 1 - do something
}

function2 = () => {
  // consumer 1 - do something
}

(async function() {
  try {
    const result = await googleLoadPromise();

    function1();
    function2();
  }
  catch( error ) {
    console.error( error );
  }
}());
```

Comment: It will run the two functions in sequence that's true. It wasn't clear that OP want's to run them all at the same time. I will add a `Promise.all` answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this sort of pattern ok?

Sure, thats the main usecase of promises.

> is the order of the running the consumers deterministic (just out of interest, more than anything)?

Yes, the callback attached first with `then` gets executed first, however I wouldnt rely on it. If you want to run one callback after another, chain them accordingly.

```
 // ok:
 promise
   .then(first);
 promise
   .then(second);

  // better if second depends on first:
 promise
   .then(first)
   .then(second);
```